# CSS Full screen background

Tags: html, css, angular

I need some help regarding CSS, I've been trying for hours to make a background be fullscreen.

This is my CSS:

```css
.mainContainer{
    width: 70%;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 100px;
}

html{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: url(../assets/background.jpg);
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

And this is my html:

```html
<html>
<div class ="mainContainer">
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
</html>
```

This semi-works the problem is the background stops as soon as my content stops, it does not continue until the end of the browser window.

Example:
[image]

I'm trying to make the background go way down there and dynamically resize with my browser.

Comment: What about `100vh` instead of `100%`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML code is missing the `body` tag. Add that, and also add `body { min-height: 100%; }`  to your CSS - this will also stretch the `body` height to at least the window's height.

Answer (score 1):

In CSS, `100%` is broken when it comes to vertical things. Try `100vh`, which is the percentage of the viewing height. Also, `100vw` is 100% of the viewing width. There are also `vmin` and `vmax`. Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Hey, 100vh helped . Thanks Redwolf Programs and @Rick van Osta. I only have one last issue, the background has a small border around it, because of this when it becomes fullscreen it adds a small scrollbar for 1-2 pixels. I even tried border: 0px !important; and it still adds it, could the border be generated by something else ?

Comment: Try outline, too. If that doesn't work, try it in another browser

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

1. Like another person said, use a `<body>` tag.
2. Add a width of 100%
3. in `background-image` rule, you should have single quotes around the URL, so it looks like: `background-image: url('../assets/background.jpg');`

Lastly, you should be using a DOCTYPE. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_declaration

```css
.mainContainer{
    width: 70%;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 100px;
}

body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/259915/pexels-photo-259915.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940');
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class ="mainContainer">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also...in the Stack Overflow code embed, I don't think you can use custom elements.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for the help, the issue was from angular material style that was overriding my background-image tag and adding borders to it for some reason.

I fixed it by adding ::ng-deep in front of html css, like this:

```
::ng-deep html{
    background-image: url('../assets/background.jpg');
    background-position: center center !important;
    background-attachment: fixed !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-size: cover !important;
}
```

Also the issue with the background not going full screen was because I was missing the body tag and body `{ min-height: 100%; }`